# The decorators plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, babeljs, next.js

I'm using Next.js with typescript. I am trying to also use TypeORM, like so:

```
@Entity()
export class UserModel extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: number
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Error: [BABEL] /home/aironside/Documents/private/tatooify/pages/api/user.ts: The decorators plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option, whose value must be a boolean. If you want to use the legacy decorators semantics, you can set the 'legacy: true' option.

Here's my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { 
      "legacy": true
     },
  ]
}
```

And here's the related package.json part

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.12.13",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

From what I found, most errors are caused by either not having this plugin installed, or it being in devDep instead of dependencies. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as shown in the [docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators) (obviously) .babelrc should be like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"legacy": true}]
  ]
}
```

Notice the [] around plugin name and options object.