# How do i enable "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators" with vite

Tags: javascript, vite

```
 > src/App.jsx:22:0: error: Unexpected "@"
    22 │ @observer

error when starting dev server:
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
src/App.jsx:22:0: error: Unexpected "@"
```

I use the observer as a decorator then i got the error. Can not find a place to enable this option in documentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you can't. Have to wait for this issue resolved: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2238

Answer (score 7):

Vite's react plugin already supports this.
Check the docs here
https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/tree/main/packages/plugin-react#proposed-syntax. You need not install any new packages. The following configuration should work,

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import reactSupport from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [reactSupport({
    babel: {
      parserOpts: {
        plugins: ['decorators-legacy', 'classProperties']
      }
    }
  })],
  server: {
    port: 3000
  }
});
```

Comment: This is not enough for Dec 2023, after you set those options you will get in the browser `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Answer (score 3):

I made a package called [vite-plugin-babel-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-babel-dev) that runs babel during dev part in Vite, if you don't need full `react` plugin.

Install `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` and use it like this:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import babelDev from 'vite-plugin-babel-dev';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        babelDev({
            babelConfig: {
                plugin: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators']
            }
        }),
        // ...
    ],

    // ...
})
```

Edit: The package is now called just [vite-plugin-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-babel)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you're using react but you can add babel plugins via the react plugin described here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-react

The recomended setup seems to require you to rename your files to `.ts / .tsx`. However, the following is allowing me to keep the `.js / .jsx` extensions.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-react
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react({
            babel: {
                plugins: [
                    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
                    [
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                        { loose: true },
                    ],
                ],
            },
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `tsDecorators` param to React plugins list in `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react({ tsDecorators: true })],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {defineConfig} from "vite"
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html';
import vueJsx from '@vitejs/plugin-vue-jsx';

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist/'
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vueJsx(
      {babelPlugins: [[
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        { legacy: true },
      ]]}
    )
  ],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slight variation, but if you're using Vite and Preact, with `@preact/preset-vite`, then you'll need to do this:

1. `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`
2. In `vite.config.ts`, add the following:

```
plugins: [
    preact({
      babel: {
        plugins: [
          ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { version: "2023-05" }],
        ],
      },
    }),
  ],
```

You might not need to set an explicit version, but it was necessary in my case to enable this error: [The decorators plugin requires a 'decoratorsBeforeExport' option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66032589/the-decorators-plugin-requires-a-decoratorsbeforeexport-option).

Comment: https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/issues/63#issuecomment-1368518960